# iOS Open in didn't work in share extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, uidocumentpickervc

in the app integrated "app extension" processing. It has "open in" functionality.
Problems that I work with special files (f.e. it has special extension - `file_name.myextension`). And when I try to do "Open In" from an email client.

[image]

I will get error: "No suitable App installed"

[image]

By the way I have updated plist file `UIDocumentPickerSupportedFileTypes` section:

```
        <key>UIDocumentPickerSupportedFileTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>.myextension</string>
            <string>public.content</string>
        </array>
```

And this is didn't help. If you have some idea, it will be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a custom filetype you have to add a new UTI.

For more infomation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html